# How can I remove chat messages from a replay?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to upload a replay that contains offensive chat messages. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to download some MPQ editor, like [Ladik MPQ Editor](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html).

Here are the steps you need to execute:

- Make a new directory like `C:\mpqeditor\`
- Copy MPQEditor.exe to C:\mpqeditor
- Copy the replay to `C:\mpqeditor\game.SC2Replay`
- Create a new empty file with Notepad and save it as `C:\mpqeditor\replay.message.events` (make sure it is not replay.message.events.txt)
- Create a new file `C:\mpqeditor\script.txt` in Notepad and copy this code into it:

```
o "game.SC2Replay"
d "game.SC2Replay" replay.message.events
a "game.SC2Replay" replay.message.events replay.message.events
c "game.SC2Replay"
```

- Open `cmd` and exectue `cd C:\mpqeditor`. You might need to open cmd as Administrator for some reason.
- Execute `MPQEditor.exe /console script.txt`

You can even create batch job out of this, see original [source](http://www.sc2sea.com/showthread.php?t=3811) for further instructions.